# Why does my function not set Firebase document but does everything else?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I've created a function that adds an image to Firebase Storage and sets the link to it, the timestamp, as well as title and content fields to a Firebase document. It then creates a subcollection and adds title and content fields to that. When the submit button is clicked, it does add the image to the Firebase storage, and adds the subcollection and the subcollection's fields. However, for some reason it doesn't always take the snapshot query that places the image link and other fields in the original collection.
I get these errors:

GET https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myheadcanon-31cf9.appspot.com/o/images%2Fljc9B3tKTQ9yLQHLqutu.png

headcanon.ca/:1 Uncaught (in promise) v {code_: "storage/object-not-found", message_: "Firebase Storage: Object 'images/ljc9B3tKTQ9yLQHLqutu.png' does not exist.", serverResponse_: "{↵  "error": {↵    "code": 404,↵    "message": "No…not get object",↵    "status": "GET_OBJECT"↵  }↵}", name_: "FirebaseError"}

What could be the cause of this?

```
var file = '';
          var fileName = '';
          var extension = '';
          const fileInput = document.getElementById("fileButton");

          fileInput.addEventListener('change',function(e){
            console.log("File added!");
              console.log(e.target);
             const selectedFiles = [...fileInput.files];
          for (const f of selectedFiles) {
            console.log(f);
          }

            file = e.target.files[0];
            console.log(file.name);
            fileName = file.name.split('.').shift();
            extension = file.name.split('.').pop();
          });
            
            document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
                var storyTitle = document.getElementById("storyTitle").value;
                var storySummary = document.getElementById("storySummary").value;
                var chapterTitle = tinymce.get("writeTitle").getContent();
                var chapterContent = tinymce.get("chapterContent").getContent();
                const myDatabase = firebase.firestore();

                addStory(storyTitle,storySummary,chapterTitle,chapterContent,file,fileName,extension);  
            });
            
            document.getElementById("updateButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
                var mainTitle = document.getElementById("storyTitle").value;
                var mainSummary = document.getElementById("storySummary").value;
                var firstChapter = tinymce.get("writeTitle").getContent();
                var firstContent = tinymce.get("chapterContent").getContent();
                const fbDatabase = firebase.firestore();
                
                console.log(mainTitle+','+mainSummary+','+firstChapter+','+firstContent);

                addStory(mainTitle,mainSummary,firstChapter,firstContent,file,fileName,extension);  
            });
    

    
async function addStory(story,summary,chapter,theContent,imageFile,imageName,extension) {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML = "Story Title: " + story + "Chapter Title: " + chapter + "Chapter Content: " + theContent;
    const storiesRef = db.collection('Stories').doc(story);
    const fbBucketName = 'images';
    const id = db.collection("Stories").doc().id;
    /*const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    const imageRef = storageRef.child(imageFile.name);
    */
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(fbBucketName+'/'+id+'.'+extension);
    const uploadTask = storageRef.put(imageFile);

uploadTask.on('state_changed',
      function(snapshot){
        
        console.log('Uploaded');
        uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL){
          storiesRef
          .set({
            title: story,
            summary: summary,
            image: downloadURL,
            timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          })
        }).then(function(){
          console.log("Upload complete!");
         imageFile='';
         imageName='';
         extension='';
        })
    });
    
    await storiesRef.collection("Chapters").add({
        title: chapter,
        content: theContent
    });
}
        </script>
    <?php
  }
}
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yeah, these two:

GET https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myheadcanon-31cf9.appspot.com/o/images%2Fljc9B3tKTQ9yLQHLqutu.png



headcanon.ca/:1 Uncaught (in promise) v {code_: "storage/object-not-found", message_: "Firebase Storage: Object 'images/ljc9B3tKTQ9yLQHLqutu.png' does not exist.", serverResponse_: "{↵ "error": {↵ "code": 404,↵ "message": "No…not get object",↵ "status": "GET_OBJECT"↵ }↵}", name_: "FirebaseError"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you care about is completion of the upload (as is the case here), I recommend using the promise of the `put` call instead of the callback(s).

That'd looks like this:

```
uploadTask.then(function(snapshot){        
  return uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
}).then(function(downloadURL){
  return storiesRef.set({
    title: story,
    summary: summary,
    image: downloadURL,
    timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  })
}).then(function(){
 console.log("Upload complete!");
 imageFile='';
 imageName='';
 extension='';
})
```